# jQuery: jCrop 'setSelect' doesn't set at all?

Tags: jquery, jcrop

I'm using `jCrop` plugin in my web application. However, I'm trying to `pre-select` an area on the image but this doesn't work at all and no area is pre-selected.

This is my code:

```
$('.position').live('click', function(){

var img = $('.selected').attr('data-image');

//create var
var jscrop_api;

//set instance to our var
$('#target').Jcrop({
      // start off with jcrop-light class
      bgOpacity: 0.5,
      bgColor: 'black',
      addClass: 'jcrop-dark',
       boxWidth: 750, 
       boxHeight: 750,
       bgFade:     true,
      setSelect: [ 60, 70, 540, 330 ]
}, function () { 
jcrop_api = this;

});

//change image for instance
jcrop_api.setImage(img);

});
```

As you can see, I'm using `setImage();` function.. So, I'm not sure if the issue is because of that?

Or, is there any z-index issue? IF z-index applies to the `setSelect` at all?

Could someone please advise on this issue?

EDIT:

Okay, I just found something that doesn't make sense but might makes sense to someone here.

If I remove the `jcrop_api.setImage(img);` and add `setImage: img,` inside my `jCrop` function. it will add the pre-selected area on the image BUT the selected image (`img`) doesn't update or appear in the crop area!

any suggestions?

Comment: What Jquery version are you using? is there any error in browser console?

Comment: @ShekharPankaj, I'm using `jquery-1.8.3.min.js` and no, there is no error in the console at all.

Comment: @ShekharPankaj, Everything works in my code and I can even select an area using my mouse. But it doesn't pre-select the area of an image on page load. I thought `setSelect:` was for that purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I can answer my own question but this worked for me:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   jcrop_api.setSelect([ ($('#target').attr('width') / 2) - 10, 
                       ($('#target').attr('height') / 2) - 10, 
                       ($('#target').attr('width') / 2) + 10, 
                       ($('#target').attr('height') / 2) + 10 
                     ]);
});
```

I hope it helps someone in my situation.